# Can you use a 3-legged OAuth Token without a web application?

Tags: autodesk-forge

Is it possible to use the 3-legged OAuth token without having some type of web application? Can you run the redirect URI to a localhost page?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, absolutely. When you define your application, create a callback url like https://localhost:3000/callback. Next, in your code create a local web server which listen port 3000 and wait for the callback.

I wrote an example [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge.commandline-nodejs) - run command:

```
node forge.js 3legged auto
```

It should start your browser, and return you the 3legged access_token.

Answer (score 0):

The redirect URI can be set to localhost but you still do need some simple web application to run on the localhost.

If you're looking for inspiration, take a look at how the [vscode-forge-tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=petrbroz.vscode-forge-tools) support a 3-legged token workflow from within Visual Studio Code. It basically starts a temporary localhost server that waits for the callback from Forge: https://github.com/petrbroz/vscode-forge-tools/blob/develop/src/commands/authentication.ts#L15-L55